# What do you mean by "Serialize a DOM Node"?

Tags: java, dom, xpath, serialization

We have been working on this piece of code where an XML is being navigated using XPATH and we want to log whatever is obtained at the xpath. While logging if we encounter an XML element then it is returning as NULL. Since [getNodeValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeValue()) returns null in case it encounters an XML element. So we want to serialize whatever we get at the XPath into a String & print it straight away in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

In the Java world, assuming DOM means W3C DOM, you have two options, either create a default `Transformer` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html with `TransformerFactory.newInstance()` and use it to feed your DOM node as a `DOMSource` to the `transform` method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#transform-javax.xml.transform.Source-javax.xml.transform.Result, with a proper Result like a `StreamResult` over a `StringWriter` so that you can then have the result as a String. Or use the `LSSerializer` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html which has a method `writeToString` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html#writeToString-org.w3c.dom.Node-. Creating an `LSSerializer` requires you to create an https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/DOMImplementationLS.html or cast a DOMImplementation to DOMImplementationLS.

There are various examples online, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html for the `Transformer` approach for instance or http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/XML/DOM/Output_XML_DOM_tree_with_LSSerializer_in_Java.htm for instance for LSSerializer.

Comment: Hye thanks for the super quick reply, but I am wondering if there is any way to serialize the entire Nodelist. In case my user were to give a XPath with child::node() and this is going to result in a Nodelist.

Comment: I don't think there is a method in the Java XML APIs to serialize a W3C DOM NodeList but it is of course trivial to implement the method on your own by iterating through the NodeList and applying on of the two methods above to each node and concatenate the results.